# polymorphic array of objects in c++ changes details of the object

Tags: c++, inheritance

I would like to make  a vector of objects of "hero" object.

this is the declaration I made:

`vector<hero*> arr;`

and these are the lines entering the object into the array(archer is an object inhert from hero)

```
archer a('a'+to_string(numPlayer),gend,hit, point, point2); 

 this->arr.insert (this->arr.begin() + numPlayer, &a);
```

It seems like everything is working, but when I try  to get the health of the object, it show me 6 but it should be 100. why is that?
I also try to get the name of the object but it gives me segmentation fault. why does it happend?

this is hero.h:

```
 #ifndef HERO_H
#define HERO_H
#include <string>
#include <math.h>
#include <map>
#include <iostream>
#include "point2d.hpp"
//#include "enemy.hpp"
using namespace std;
#include "actors.hpp"

class hero:public actors{
    protected:
        string name; 
        int size; 
        char gender; 
        double health; 
        double hitting;
        point2d point, goal;
        double radius;


    public:

        hero(string name, char gender, double damage, point2d point, point2d goal);
        hero(const  hero &hero);
        ~hero();
        string getName();
        char getGender();
        double getDamage();
        point2d getPoint();
        double getHealth();

        void setName(string name);
        void setGender(char gender);
        void setDamage(double damage);
        void setHealth(double health);
        void setPoint(point2d point);
        string toString(); ///const in the end!!!!
        bool move(map<string, char> &matrix, vector<potion> potions );
        double getRadius();


       void hurt(double hit);

};

class warrior :public hero{
public:

    warrior(string name, char gender, double damage, point2d point, point2d point2);
    warrior(warrior &w);
    ~warrior();




};

class archer :public hero{
public:

    archer(string name, char gender,  double damage, point2d point, point2d point2);
    archer(archer &a);
    ~archer();



};

class wizard :public hero{
public:

    wizard(string name, char gender,  double damage, point2d point, point2d point2);
    wizard(wizard &a);
    ~wizard();
};

#endif
```

and these are archer and hero constructors

```
hero::hero(string name, char gender, double damage, point2d point,point2d point2){    
        this->name = name;
        this->gender=gender;
        this->health=100;
        this->hitting=damage;
        this->point = point2d(point);
        this->goal=point2d(point2);
        this->size=0;

}

archer::archer(string name, char gender, double damage, point2d point, point2d point2):
    hero(name, gender,  damage, point, point2) {
```

}

this is the get: `cout<<this->arr.at(0)->getHealth();`
 // output is 6

```
cout<<this->arr.at(0)->getName();
```

//output:bash: line 12: 23084 Segmentation fault      $file.o $args

Comment: The right tool to solve such problems is your debugger. You should step through your code line-by-line *before* asking on Stack Overflow. For more help, please read [How to debug small programs (by Eric Lippert)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). At a minimum, you should \[edit] your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example that reproduces your problem, along with the observations you made in the debugger.

Comment: `&a` ? Something tells me by the time you actually perform your inspection and/or name print from the pointer you're storing in that vector that `a` has *long* since been destroyed due to exiting the scope where it was created. In short, my crystal ball tells me you're loading your vector with what ultimately becomes a dangling pointer.

Comment: BTW, the warrior, archer and wizard classes do NOT have copy constructors (missing const keyword).

Comment: First of all do you really need to have vector of pointers? Why not just store it directly(vector<hero> arr)? Also your parent class doesn't have a virtual destructor which may cause undefined behaviour.

Comment: @MarošBeťko In such situation, the author could not use the polymorphism due to object slicing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in the way of adding the heroes to `vector`:

```
archer a('a' + to_string(numPlayer), gend, hit, point, point2); 
this->arr.insert(this->arr.begin() + numPlayer, &a);
```

Here you insert a pointer to local variable to your storage. When the execution flow leaves the current block, your archer `a` is destroyed, and the memory it uses may be used for other objects (which change the former `health` field as well as pointer to the name). For more information, please check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6441218/can-a-local-variables-memory-be-accessed-outside-its-scope).

To fix this, you should allocate your archer on heap, like this:

```
archer* a = new archer('a' + to_string(numPlayer), gend, hit, point, point2); 
this->arr.insert(this->arr.begin() + numPlayer, a);
```

This code will probably work correctly, but there's one more flaw: looks like the container `arr` should own all the heroes belonging to it, managing their life time to avoid memory (and other resources) leaks. To achieve this, you may use the smart pointers, like this:

```
vector<unique_ptr<hero>> arr;
...
auto a = make_unique<archer>('a' + to_string(numPlayer), gend, hit, point, point2); 
this->arr.insert(this->arr.begin() + numPlayer, move(a));
```

For more information on smart pointers, please see these:

1. [Cppreference documentation of make_unique](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/make_unique).
2. [Core c++ guidelines](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md), they have some rules about smart pointers as well as on many other themes.